# Switch to the next children route with condition in angular

Tags: angular, routes

I want to make a custom router in Angular. 
Here is my example router from [Angular document](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration) with some changes :

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisPublicComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

There are two children under `main` path. **Both children have the same path!!!** I know this is impossible in this code. However I want to have these components with the same path **with the condition** if `user` is `authorized` we load `first child` if not load the `second child`.  I know we can do it in some ways such as `ng-container` with condition in the component but I want to know if I could have a custom `router`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is a route guard. A route guard allows you to perform a check (such as whether the user is authorized). If the check is true, you route to the defined route. Otherwise you route to an alternate route.

Your route configuration would then just have the one "happy path" route. The route guard would route the user to the "failed authorization" path using code.

Here is an example path:

```
            {
                path: 'movies',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                component: MovieListComponent
            },
```

And here is the route guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router,
         CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export  class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
    }

    checkLoggedIn(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Retain the attempted URL for redirection
        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);   // <-- Here is the alternate route
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the user is authorized, they are routed to the primary route defined in the path (MovieListComponent in my example.) If the user is not authorized, the guard routes the user to the login route as shown above.

You can find the complete working example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Comment: Thanks! However, I need to stay in the same route and show user different content (Public content).